# If the perimeter of a rectangle A and a square B are same what is the relation between their areas?

Tags: geometry

If the perimeter of a rectangle A and a square B are same what is the relation between their areas?

a) A > B
b) A < B
c) A = B

Comment: Hint: $ab \le \dfrac{(a+b)^2}4$

Comment: what is the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rectangle has non-equal side lengths $a,b$, then the square has side lengths of $(a+b)/2$. Now compute the area of the square $((a+b)/2)^2 = a^2/4 + ab/2 + b^2/2$, and subtract the area of the rectangle which is $ab$. You get $a^2/4 - ab/2 + b^2/4 = (a-b)^2/4$ which is positive because $a \neq b$, so the square has more area.